# Eclipse Paho can not keep connection

Tags: eclipse, mqtt

I tried to using eclipse paho on Mosquitto and ActiveMQ.
When keepalive less than 30 seconds, everything is ok.
when keepalive more than 30 seconds, server will disconnect it after about 5 mins.

```
1351161274: Client charles_subscribe has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, we are now diagnosing this in Eclipse Bugzilla - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392825

Comment: This was fixed in newer versions of the Paho client library.